# Maatwebsite, import excel to mysql in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a website project in laravel, I want to import from excel to mysql, there is a formula, but the formula cannot be imported into mysql, which appears the formula itself[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W3jF.png)

```
Array
            (
                [0] => 9119030205840002
                [1] => SAMPLE
                [2] => L
                [3] => TMPT_LHR
                [4] => 30804
                [5] => AB
                [6] => 1
                [7] => STATUS
                [8] => SHDK
                [9] => 1
                [10] => PDDK_AKHIR
                [11] => PEKERJAAN
                [12] => NAMA_IBU
                [13] => NAMA_AYAH
                [14] => 9119032209080058
                [15] => NAMA_KEP_KEL
                [16] => ALAMAT
                [17] => NAMA_PROP
                [18] => NAMA_KAB
                [19] => NAMA_KEC
                [20] => NAMA_KEL
                [21] => =_xlfn.IFERROR(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","*",LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""))))),"")
            )
```

Comment: What does it means `formula cannot be imported`? You have a problem with double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;

```
class ExcelImport implements ToCollection, WithCalculatedFormulas
```